# Marking your own answer as correct?

Tags: discussion

In [This thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35586/how-to-mount-a-torch-to-camera/35667?noredirect=1#comment59410_35667) I've 'answered' my own question but i'm thinking that perhaps I shouldn't have done this? 
Would it have been better to instead add the info from my answer into the question instead? Currently its my only solution for this issue (although it hasn't been very long since I posted the question as dpollit pointed out).

Is there a 'rule' around when you can answer your own questions?

If the consensus is that my answer in the thread is in the wrong place I'm happy to move it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 6):

Answering your own question is not only acceptable, it is encouraged even. It is right in our FAQ and detailed here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

The reason I commented on your accepted answer was noting why I downvoted it. Which was of course not because you answered it, it was because of the content of the answer.

> You asked for "a cleaner solution" to "hacking". 
>   I'm downvoting this because it did not provide a cleaner solution. It looks like a terribly dirty hack to me.

I don't believe the answer, answered the question! That's exactly what downvotes on answers are for :)

Comment: Yeah, this. And to emphasize, please _don't_ edit your answer into the question. See [this](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/should-edits-which-add-the-accepted-answer-to-the-question-be-reverted) for more.

Comment: I have often had questions that I've asked that end up with no good answer.  When this happens, I keep digging to try and find the answer and then post it when I find it.  The more in depth your knowledge the more likely this is to happen since the more complex the question, the harder it can be to answer, but also the more valuable it can be if the question is broadly applicable enough.